# Could I add a button with javascript in the portal of SQL Server Reporting Services?

Tags: javascript, html, reporting-services, power-bi-report-server

Could I add a button with javascript in the branding portal of SQL Server Reporting Services?

I know there is standard branding customization of SSRS but it's just changing the color and graph. 
I need to add button with javascript action in the header of the portal for certain business requirement.

[image]

Is it possible?

Please help. thanks.

Comment: Yes it's possible, since SSRS spits out .asp pages. MSDN has this same question with the steps you have to go through: search `SSRS include javascript`. Try implementing it and then come back here when you get stuck on coding Else this question will probably be closed for not including an example or being off topic on stack overflow.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the thing you just mentioned is to add javascript in ssrs reports. but what i want is to add javascript action button or link in the "Portal top area as the above graph.